# Google Cloud SQL: Periodic Read Spikes Associated With Loss of Connectivity

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have noticed that my Google Cloud SQL instance is losing connectivity periodically and it seems to be associated with some read spikes on the Cloud SQL instance. See the attached screenshot for examples.

The instance is mostly idle, but my application recycles connections in the connection pool every 60 seconds so this is not a wait_timeout issue. I have verified that the connection are recycled Also, it occurred twice in 30 minutes and the wait_timeout is 8 hours.

I would suspect a backup process but you can see from the screenshot that no backups have run.

The first instance lasted 17 seconds from the time the connection loss was detected until it was reestablished. The second was only 5 seconds, but given that my connections are idle for 60 seconds the actual downtime could be up to 1:17 and 1:05 respectively. They occurred at 2014-06-05 15:29:08 UTC and 2014-06-05 16:05:32 UTC respectively. The read spikes are not initiated by me. My app continued to be idle during the issue so this is some sort of internal GCS process.

This is not a big deal for my idle app, but it will become a big deal when the app is not idle.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Is this a known issue with Google Cloud SQL? Is there a known fix?

Any help would be appreciated.

****Update****

The root cause of the symptoms above has been identified as a restart of the MySQL instance.  I did not restart the instance and the operations section of the web console does not list any events at that time, so now the question becomes, what would cause the instance to restart twice in 30 minutes? Why would a production database instance restart period?

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was caused by one of our regular release. Because of the way the update takes place an instance might be restarted more than once during the push to production.

Comment: This looks like the answer, but I was under the impression that Cloud SQL was replicated with auto-failover. Shouldn't the system have taken down the slave, upgraded it, brought it back online, taken down the master, failed over to the slave, upgraded the master, then brought the master online? Wouldn't that have limited downtime to the instant the master was failing over rather than the time it took to completely restart the server?

Also, if there is some maintenance that requires downtime shouldn't there be some sort of notice via email of when that maintenance window will occur?

Comment: That's not how the Cloud SQL works. There is no slave because the data is replicated at file level ([How is my data replicated?](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#replication)). More details about the maintenance shutdowns can be found in the [What kind of maintenance shutdowns should I expect with my instance?](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#maintenancerestart).

Answer (score 0):

Was your instance restarted ? During the restart the spinning down/up of an instance will trigger read/write.

That may be one reason why you are seeing the activity for read/write.

Comment: It was not restarted by me. No events are listed in the operations section of the web console that would indicate a restart. A check of `show global status like '%uptime%'` does show that it was restarted at the time of the spike though. So the root cause is a restart of the server. What would cause that twice in 30 minutes? What would cause that on a production database instance at all?

Comment: Restarts can occur due to upgrades, migration between zones, infrastructure work, if the App Engine application moves and the instance is configured to follow it.